# Excel Protected Data Source For Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am exporting reports from QuickBooks Online as Excel attachments via email. I am then using Microsoft Flow to save the attachments to Sharepoint. Then, I am using those Excel files stored in Sharepoint as the data source for my reporting. I have one report (out of 7) that's coming through with a protected view, which is causing it to look like this in Power Query:
[image]

The actual Excel file looks like this when I open it:
[image]

From what I can deduce, this is because there's some level of protection on the Excel file. However, the other theory I have is because each of the cells have "=" before the numeric value. In other words, the first cell has "=750" instead of just "750". If I go into Sharepoint, open the file in Excel Online, remove the "=" in **just that one cell**, and refresh Power Query, then the amounts show up in the editor as expected.

Is there any way to deal with this in Power Query? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what happens if you change the column data types to text rather that numbers, will it show the blank rows? Also check the excel cell formatting

Comment: Apart from what Jonee said, if they show correctly, try to change the format using locale (right click the column and select the column types -> using locale)

Comment: Neither of those solutions work, unfortunately.